# Multi Column Picker for Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am building a multi-column picker control, and I have some issues with the xamarin.ios renderer.

I have two columns in the picker. One for the month and another for the year. I have got the values binded to the picker control properly. However when I make a selection the app crashes.

The error is `Specified cast is not valid.`

Stacktrace is

`` at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PickerRendererBase`1[TControl].OnEnded 
   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x0000b] in 
   <0648e2dffe9e4201b8c6e274ced6579f>:0 at 
   UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00004] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.16.0.5/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:38 ``

My ios Custom Renderer code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CoreGraphics;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(YearMonthPicker), typeof(YearMonthPickerRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.iOS.Renderers
{
public class YearMonthPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    private MonthYear _monthYear = new MonthYear();
    private UILabel _monthLabel;
    private UILabel _yearLabel;
    public YearMonthPickerRenderer()
    {
        _monthYear.Months = new List<string>();
        _monthYear.Years = new List<int>();
        InitValues();
    }

    private void InitValues()
    {
        _monthYear.Months = new List<string>{
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "Sepetember",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        };
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var customPicker = e.NewElement as YearMonthPicker;
            var startYear = customPicker.StartYear;
            var endYear = customPicker.EndYear;

            do
            {
                _monthYear.Years.Add(startYear);
                startYear++;
            } while (startYear <= endYear);

            if (_monthLabel == null)
            {
                _monthLabel = new UILabel();
                _monthLabel.Text = customPicker.MonthLabel;
                _monthLabel.TextColor = customPicker.LabelColor.ToUIColor();
                _monthLabel.Font = _monthLabel.Font.WithSize(14.0f);
            }
            if (_yearLabel == null)
            {
                _yearLabel = new UILabel();
                _yearLabel.Text = customPicker.YearLabel;
                _yearLabel.TextColor = customPicker.LabelColor.ToUIColor();
                _yearLabel.Font = _yearLabel.Font.WithSize(14.0f);
            }
            if (Control is UITextField textField)
            {
                var pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
                var yearMonthModel = new YearMonthModel(textField, _monthYear);
                var yearMonthDelegate = new YearMonthPickerDelegate(textField, _monthYear);
                pickerView.Model = yearMonthModel;
                pickerView.Delegate = yearMonthDelegate;
                textField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                textField.AddSubview(_monthLabel);
                textField.AddSubview(_yearLabel);
            }
        }
        var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, Control.Frame.Size.Width, 44.0f));

        toolbar.Items = new[]
        {
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            new UIBarButtonItem("Done",
                UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
                delegate {
                    Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                })
        };

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        }


    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();



        _monthLabel.Frame = new CGRect(0, -10,
                                      Control.Frame.Width / 2,
                                      Control.Frame.Height - 5);

        _yearLabel.Frame = new CGRect(Control.Frame.Width / 2, -10,
                                      Control.Frame.Width / 2,
                                      Control.Frame.Height - 5);


    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _monthLabel?.Dispose();
        _yearLabel?.Dispose();
        _monthLabel = null;
        _yearLabel = null;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}

public class YearMonthModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    private UITextField _uITextField;
    private string _selectedMonth = string.Empty;
    private string _selectedYear = string.Empty;
    private MonthYear _monthYear;
    public YearMonthModel(UITextField uITextField, MonthYear monthYear)
    {
        _uITextField = uITextField;
        _monthYear = monthYear;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return _monthYear.Months.Count;
        else
            return _monthYear.Years.Count;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return _monthYear.Months[(int)row];
        else
            return _monthYear.Years[(int)row].ToString();
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            _selectedMonth = _monthYear.Months[(int)row];
        if (component == 1)
            _selectedYear = _monthYear.Years[(int)row].ToString();
        _uITextField.Text = $"{_selectedMonth} {_selectedYear}";
    }

    public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return 140f;
        else
            return 100f;
    }

    public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
    {
        return 40f;
    }
}

public class YearMonthPickerDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    private UITextField _uITextField;
    private string _selectedMonth = string.Empty;
    private string _selectedYear = string.Empty;
    private MonthYear _monthYear;
    public YearMonthPickerDelegate(UITextField uITextField, MonthYear monthYear)
    {
        _uITextField = uITextField;
        _monthYear = monthYear;
    }
    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0)
            return _monthYear.Months[(int)row];
        else
            return _monthYear.Years[(int)row].ToString();
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {

        if (component == 0)
            _selectedMonth = _monthYear.Months[(int)row];
        if (component == 1)
            _selectedYear = _monthYear.Years[(int)row].ToString();
        _uITextField.Text = $"{_selectedMonth} {_selectedYear}";
    }
}

public class MonthYear
{
    public List<string> Months { get; set; }
    public List<int> Years { get; set; }
}
```

}

Edit 1
 I am adding the YearMonthPicker class

```
public class YearMonthPicker : Picker
{
    public YearMonthPicker()
    {
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty StartYearProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(StartYear), typeof(int), typeof(YearMonthPicker), 1900);

    public int StartYear
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StartYearProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartYearProperty, value); }
    }



    public static readonly BindableProperty EndYearProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EndYear), typeof(int), typeof(YearMonthPicker), 9999);

    public int EndYear
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(EndYearProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndYearProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YearLabelProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YearLabel), typeof(string), typeof(YearMonthPicker), string.Empty);

    public string YearLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(YearLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YearLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MonthLabelProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MonthLabel), typeof(string), typeof(YearMonthPicker), string.Empty);

    public string MonthLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MonthLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MonthLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelColorProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelColor), typeof(Color), typeof(YearMonthPicker), default(Color));

    public Color LabelColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LabelColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I appreciate if someone can help me identify what causes the crash.

Comment: Can you please share the code of YearMonthPicker?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : I have added the YearMonthPicker Class too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found your problem is you did not assign the pickerView to the textField's inputView.

To assign the picker to the textField's inputView, use below code:

```
        if (Control is UITextField textField)
        {
            //Change here
            var pickerView = new UIPickerView();
            Control.InputView = pickerView;

            var yearMonthModel = new YearMonthModel(textField, _monthYear);
            var yearMonthDelegate = new YearMonthPickerDelegate(textField, _monthYear);
            pickerView.Model = yearMonthModel;
            pickerView.Delegate = yearMonthDelegate;
            textField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            textField.AddSubview(_monthLabel);
            textField.AddSubview(_yearLabel);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Jack Hua. That fixed it :)